# Fluid CSS container without spaces

Tags: html, css

Wrong:
[image]

Correct:
[image]

How to achieve that (without spaces between elements) ? They also must be centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="header container">
    <div class="col col-1">
        <input type="text" class="text small" name="search" placeholder="Search suppliers">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
        <div class="styled-select">
            <select>
                <option>asd</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
        <a href="#" class="classname">Reset</a>
        <a href="#" class="classname2">Search</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.col {
    width:20%;
}
```

Anyone can help with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set all `div.col` with inline-block positioning and set `'text-align:center'` on your container to center it horizontally.

```
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.container .col {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Agreed `+1`. I'm not sure why others are suggesting adding a wrapping container and floating elements when a simple centering and inline-block works.

Comment: @andyb i dunno, maybe for IE6... but the total-width must be known, it's not really easy to maintain

Comment: Well the image in the question looks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which doesn't support IE6 so I assumed Thomas (like a lot of developers) does not need to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block`.

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height:120px;
    text-align:center;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Also, to remove spaces between each `.col`, make sure that there is no white space between each *opening* and *closing* div tag.

```
<div class="header container">
    <div class="col col-1">
        <input type="text" class="text small" name="search" placeholder="Search suppliers">
    </div><div class="col col-2"> <!-- THIS LINE - no white-space -->
        <div class="styled-select">
            <select>
                <option>asd</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div><div class="col col-3"> <!-- THIS LINE - no white-space also -->
          <a href="#" class="classname">Reset</a>
          <a href="#" class="classname2">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Doorknob, it is NOT if the element has `display: inline-block`. There would be a small gap between each div.

Comment: Actually, whitespace can some times be seen in older browsers such as IE8. Causing layout issues.

Comment: Okay, I should have phrased that better: all consecutive whitespace characters are treated as one whitespace character (and the rest are effectively ignored).

Comment: I didn't say they're not. The problem though, is this single white-space.

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly what you want, you'll need an extra HTML wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/h37J4/

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height:120px;
}
.header > .row {
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden; /*quick cleafix hack */
}
.col {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yoou need a wrapper for the content like this:

```
<div class="header container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="col col-1">
               <input type="text" class="text small" name="search" placeholder="Search suppliers">
            </div>
            <div class="col col-2">
              <div class="styled-select">
                <select>
                    <option>asd</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-3">
              <a href="#" class="classname">Reset</a>
              <a href="#" class="classname2">Search</a>
            </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

And then style the wrapper with css, something like this:

```
.header .wrapper {
    width: 70%; /* or any in px */
    margin: 0 auto; /* for centering */
}
```

**Or you can just replace your ".header" element's 100% width with smaller number!**